# Android toolbar menu doesn't work properly when I even set shoAsAction as always

Tags: android, menu, toolbar

here is my code

```
fun initActionBar() {
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar_main)
    actionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
    MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
    return true
}
```

and here I serve you my menu and screenshot
[image: 1]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '?' after actionBar. Looks like this now:

```
fun initActionBar() {
setSupportActionBar(toolbar_main)
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

}

override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?): Boolean {
MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.toolbar_menu, menu)
return true
}
```